# Use of Binder Cumulant for Determining Critical Temperature

Tags: statistical-mechanics, computational-physics, phase-transition, ising-model, statistics

I am completing a computational project where I am simulating the Ising model using Monte Carlo methods, namely the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm, and the Wolff algorithm.

For the Metropolis-Hastings approach, I found the phase transition in the magnetisation of a cubic lattice with periodic boundary conditions for three lattice sizes of $5^3$, $10^3$, and $15^3$. For each temperature in the range of temperatures being investigated, I allowed the system to equilibrate and then collected independent values of magnetisation (separated by some multiple of the autocorrelation time) over some tens of thousands of Monte Carlo steps and then averaged over these independent values. I then repeated this 20 times at each temperature, resulting in a dataset of twenty average values of magnetisation for each temperature.

After some research, I found that I could find the critical temperature by finding the intersection of the Binder cumulant in (1) for each lattice size.

$$U_4=1-\frac{<M^4>}{3<M^2>^2}\tag1$$

However, from the resulting graph there is no intersection of curves in the region where I know the critical temperature should be ($K_c≈0.222$), suggesting that something is wrong with my method, my data, or both.

Does anyone have any advice for how to fix this issue and improve estimation of critical temperature?

[image]

Comment: There is surely an issue since far in the disordered phase, the spins should follow a gaussian (because they are uncorrelated) and hence, the binder cumulant should go to 0 because the 4th moment of a gaussian random variable is equal to 3 times the variance squared.

Comment: I agree with Syrocco. 
I'd also advice looking into quantities like the magnetization squared to see if they are behaving in the expected way. Looking at this graph, there seems something wrong with the disordered phase. Looking into magnetization^2 also comes with the benefit that it's easier to estimate because it only involves lower order cumulants.